# Image not downloading in Android

Tags: android

I have a bit of code that was working, but now isn't and I can't figure out why. I am trying to download an image from a URL, but nothing is being retrieved. I have the following code:

```
URL u;
u = new URL("https://sites.google.com/site/mymoneymobilesite/rugbynut/leagues/league%20six%20nations.png");
URLConnection ucon = u.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
Bitmap tmp_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Like I say, this was working months ago, but I've come to update some other code and found that it isn't anymore.

Can anyone help please?

UPDATE:
I have tried the code:

```
InputStream iStream = (InputStream) u.getContent();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(iStream, "test");
```

but d is null. I use the same URL as above (the image is publicly available) and the application has no issues with connecting to the internet, as it is managing to download other data.

Any more ideas?

Comment: any more specific error ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You might have not given permission for internet access in the manifest file.
2. Note that to fetch the image from URL either use AsyncTask or a different thread, as the fetch operation can't be performed in the main thread.
3. Try images at other links maybe the link you are trying is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
  try {
      InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
      Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
      return d;
  } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code..

```
public static Drawable ImageOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

It is working cool for me. I also faced this kind of error before, It is hard to find the exact error. Basically when internet is slow or image is large then it occurs . But this code works every times..